# Securing Azure Functions with JWT token in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-functions

I have a Blazor web assembly stand alone app secured by an AAD B2C tenant.

The app calls an ASP.NET Web API which is configured to accept an access token:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        },
        options => { builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); }
        );

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Everything is working fine, I get the token (and I can access the User object) and I receive a 401 if the token is missing.

I would like to do the same using Azure Functions instead. I have created the project and added the services:

```cs
    .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
    {
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                {
                    host.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                },
                options => { host.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); }
                );
    })
```

but I don't know which is the equivalent of

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

given that I do not have an `IApplicationBuilder` but an `IHost` instead.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Giorgio Di Nardo, 
I think In Azure Functions, you can configure authentication and authorization by using the AuthorizationLevel attribute on individual functions. The equivalent of app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization() is applied at the function level.

Comment: hi @MohamedAzarudeenZ, thanks for you answer. unfortunately, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4, it seems it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control authorization the same way you do in ASP.NET Core, the short answer would be it's not supported by Micrsoft because Azure Functions rely on the `AuthorizationLevel` property within `HttpTriggerAttribute` you use to decorate your `HttpRequest` (v3, v4, Isolated with ASP.NET integration) or `HttpRequestData` (Isolated worker). The expectation is the use of pre-shared keys when using them.

##### Solution

- Use [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize](https://nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorize) for In-Process function apps
- Use [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.Isolated](https://nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.Isolated) for Isolated with ASP.NET Core integration function apps

These packages allow you to configure the authentication with the same ASP.NET infrastructure that you already know (`services.AddAuth...`)

> For in-process model there are extension methods wrapping ASP.NET ones to not break Azure Portal's access to your function. `services.AddFunctionsAuthentication(...`

Then all you have to do is just use the classic `AuthorizeAttribute` (Isolated) and `FunctionAuthorizeAttribute` (in-proc) on top of your function types and methods the same way you do for your controllers and you are ready to roll.

Hope this helps. Here is a [post](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functions-policy-based-auth-for-functions-v4-in-proc-and-isolated) with some explanation and samples.